# How to capture an image and save it (Uri)?

Tags: java, android, image, camera

Using the following code, what do I add in order to save the captured image and also extract the URI of that image for immediate use; that use is specifically adding the URI to an HashMap and possibly calling it to an imageview right after.

Here is my code:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

onActivityResult:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_HAPPY_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_SURPRISED_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_AFRAID_PHOTO ||
              requestCode == REQUEST_UPSET_PHOTO || requestCode == REQUEST_SAD_PHOTO) {
        final boolean isCamera;
        if (data == null) {
            isCamera = true;
        } else {
            final String action = data.getAction();
            if (action == null) {
                isCamera = false;
            } else {
                isCamera = action.equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
        Uri selectedImageUri;
        if (isCamera) {
            selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
        } else {
            selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
        }
```

I also have a create file method for the image:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp;
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pass file while launching intent then use it after capturing.

```
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
```

**Full Demo working on all versions.**

For both Capture and pick image

Note: Android 6.0 get runtime permissions on click then procced.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView camera, gallery;
    File photoFile;
    Uri uri;
    private final static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private final static int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img);
        gallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

            }
        });
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            photoFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/myimage/save.jpg");
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            uri = data.getData();
            String selecteadImage = getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                String selecteadImage = getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    String selecteadImage = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest Permissions:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**activity_main:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Capturing image [for more](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

```
String mCurrentPhotoPath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
    storageDir      /* directory */
);

// Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
return image;
}
```

You can simply do this to rename the image

```
File outFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "imagename.jpeg");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); 
fos.flush();
fos.close();
```

By adding permission in android-manifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

for retrieving uri

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(getFileStreamPath(outFile));
```

Hope this will help